# $U = (-1,1) \times (-1,1) \times \cdots$ is not open in the uniform topology

Tags: general-topology

Am I right that the set 
\begin{equation}
U = (-1,1) \times (-1,1) \times \cdots
\end{equation}
in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not open in the uniform topology? 
Because we can't find a basis open in the uniform topology that contains for example the sequence $\big(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and is contained in $U$.

Thanks

Comment: @Alex: Almost: $d_u(x,y)=\sup_n\min\{1,|x_n-y_n|\}$.

Comment: Yes, you’re right: $U$ is open in the box topology but not in the uniform topology.

Comment: Yes. For each $k$ define a sequence $(x_n)^k\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ by putting $(x_n)^k=1-\frac 1{n+1}$ if $n\le k$ and $(x_n)^k=1$, otherwise. Then $(x_n)^k\subset \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\setminus U$, but in uniformly converges to  $\big(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\big)_n$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! My idea was that for any open ball $B_{d_u} (x, \delta)$ ,$x=(1- \frac{1}{n+1})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$,  in the uniform topology , one can take the sequence $ (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (1- \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{\delta}{2} )_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. This sequence is in that open ball, but is not in $U$. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. Because when $n+1>2/\delta$ we have $y_n>1$.